# How to exclude certain paths from data stream in google analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics-4

We often have accidental url's logged in GA4 on our site that have `/admin.php`  as part of the URL'

Is there a way of permanently excluding certain paths from being recorded at all?

Such as if URL contains `_admin`  then exclude.